# How to make the flow lines in mermaid flowchart to exact 90 degrees?

Tags: flowchart, mermaid

I'm using Mermaid to create a simple flow diagram as shown below. I'd like to make the connecting lines to exact 90 degree but couldn't able to find documentation anywhere .

Is it possible to make it exact 90 degrees ?

```
flowchart TD 
    B["fa:fa-twitter for peace"] 
    B-->C[fa:fa-ban forbidden] 
    B-->D(fa:fa-spinner); 
    B-->E(A fa:fa-camera-retro perhaps?);
```

**Actual Flow :**

[image: Actual]

**Expected Flow :**

[image: expected]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prepend with the following init pragma. More options are available here: https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=styling-line-curves

`%%{ init: { 'flowchart': { 'curve': 'stepAfter' } } }%%`

See example below. Feel free to tweak it to your liking.

```
%%{ init: { 'flowchart': { 'curve': 'stepAfter' } } }%%
flowchart TD
    A["A"] --- T1( )
    T1---B[B] 
    T1---C[C]
    T1---D[D]
```

[image: mermaid flowchart with 90deg elbows]

Answer (score 1):

There's been [an open issue](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/2549) on the Github repo about this for a couple of months, now. It doesn't look like it's possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, since version 9.4 the renderer can be changed to achieve the result you want:

**Code:**

```
---
config:
    flowchart:
        defaultRenderer: elk
---
flowchart TD 
    B["fa:fa-twitter for peace"] 
    B-->C[fa:fa-ban forbidden] 
    B-->D(fa:fa-spinner); 
    B-->E(A fa:fa-camera-retro perhaps?);
```

**Reuslt:**
[image]